# Why does this pointer to pointer to char result in a warning?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have

```
char *greeting = "Hello";
char *names[] = { "Tom", "Jerry" };
```

I can declare a pointer to a pointer to char for `names`, like this

```
char **names2 = names;
```

but I can NOT do so for `greeting`.

I get *warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type.*

Why? `greeting` is a pointer to `char`, just as `names` is an array of pointers to `char`, so why can't I declare a pointer to `greeting`?

Comment: `char **names3 = &greeting;`, also Name of the array represents the address of the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to use 1x *!

Because char * and char ** are different types!

So you tried to assign a variable with the type char * to a variable with the type char **

And that gives you a warning

So this should work:

```
char *greeting = "Hello";               
char *names[] = { "Tom", "Jerry" };    

char *greeting2 = greeting;           //Type char *
char **names2 = names;                //Type char **
```

Comment: The type of `names` is not `char **`. It does however decay to that type when used in an expression ... e.g., the initializer for `names2`.

Comment: Thank you. And as BLUEPIXY noted, I could have used `char **names2 = &greeting;`

Answer (score -1):

In C, pointers and arrays are closely associated.

Doing something like:

```
char* names[] = {"Tom","Jerry"};
```

Is the same as doing something like

```
char** names = {"Tom", "Jerry"};
```

A `char*` value cannot be assigned to a `char**` value, because they're of different types.

---

Let's look at the same thing from an array perspective.
The two variables can be declared as follows:

```
char greeting[8] = "Hello";
char names[][5] = { "Tom", "Jerry" };
```

The above example should make it clear, that `greetings` is a single dimensioned array whereas `names` is a two-dimensioned array and the two are therefore incompatible

Comment: This is wrong: `char** names[] = {"Tom", "Jerry"};`

Comment: @wildplasser yeah, typo!

Comment: "Doing something like: char* names[] = {"Tom","Jerry"};
Is the same as doing something like char** names = {"Tom", "Jerry"};" -- No, it's nothing like that. The latter has too many initializers, and the initializer(s) has the wrong type. "A char* value cannot be assigned to a char** value, because they're of different types" -- and yet you're trying to assign "Tom" to a `char**`. "pointers and arrays are closely associated" -- This is a common misunderstanding. Arrays decay to pointers to their first element in expression contexts, but they are otherwise unrelated to pointers.